# How to apply the finite correction error to adjust the required sample size

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, finite-population

I am currently refreshing my stats knowledge where I came across the notion of the finite population correction. This notion appears when determining the sample size required to construct a confidence interval, and some parts of the explanation are confusing to me. I have outlined the issue below.

Suppose we want to construct a confidence interval for the mean $\mu$ of a population distribution. We are asked to explain how to obtain the minimum required sample size for a specified confidence level (call it $q$) and absolute precision $D$. Suppose for simplicity that the population variance $\sigma^2$ is known.

First, one determines the $z$ - score corresponding the the confidence level $q$, denote it by $z_q$. Then from the formula 
$$ \tag 1
D= z_q \cdot \text{standard error} = z_q \cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
one obtains that
$$ \tag 2
n = \left\lceil\frac{z_q^2\cdot \sigma^2}{D^2}\right\rceil
$$
where $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ is the ceiling function. Now according to the notes that I'm using for my studies, if $n$ is $\ge 10 \%$ of the size of the target population $N$ then one has to apply the finite population correction to the resulting $n$.

This is where I get confused because I thought that the finite population correction would have to be applied earlier, namely to correct the standard error. So, instead of multiplying the right hand side of equation $(1)$ by $\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}$ I thought that one has to replace $(2)$ with the expression
$$
D=z_q \cdot \text{standard error}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}= z_q \cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}
$$
and then solve for $n$.

I think these approaches give different answers (I haven't checked this yet but I will) and I am not sure which one is to be applied -- mathematically the latter seems more robust to me.